# Give us some votes for our adverts

Tags: discussion, advertisement

We have some advertisements for expats on other network sites.  They need more than 6 votes to appear, however. Please do give them a vote, and let us know if you've placed them anywhere else!

[Advert on Academia](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/907/community-promotion-ads-2014/1124#1124)

[Advert on Travel](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1642/101)